# Do you need to fully validate data both in Database and Application?

Tags: sql, database

For example, if I need to store a valid phone number in a database, should I fully validate the number in SQL, or is it enough if I fully validate it in the app, before inserting it in the db, and just add some light validation in SQL constraints (like having the correct number of digits).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no correct answer to this question.

In general, you want the *database* to maintain data integrity -- and that includes valid values in columns.  You want this for multiple reasons:

- Databases are usually more efficient, because they are on multi-threaded servers.
- Databases can handle concurrent threads (not an issue for a check constraint, but an issue for other types of constraints).
- Databases ensure the data integrity *regardless of how the data is changed*.
- A check constraint (presumably what you want) is part of the data definition and applies to *all* inserts and updates.  Such operations might occur in multiple places in the application.

The third piece is important.  If you want to ensure that a phone number looks like a phone number, then you don't want someone to change it accidentally using `update`.

However, there might be checks that are simpler in the application.  Or that might only apply when a new row is inserted, but not later updated.  Or, that you want only to apply to data that comes in from the application (as opposed to manual changes).  So, there are reasons why you might not want to do all checks in the database.

Answer (score 2):

You definitily have to validate incoming data at your backend before e.g. doing crud operations on your database, since client side validation could bei omitted or even faked. It is considered to be a good practise to validate input data at the client. But you should never ever trust the client.